# Fragment.onCreateView has null container

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

The following is running on an Android 1.6 so I'm using the compatibility package for fragments. In the following `TestFragment` is a static nested class:

```
public class FragmentTestActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public static class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView result = new TextView(getActivity());
        result.setText("Hello TestFragment");
        return result;
    }
}
```

}

The main.xml file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<fragment class="com.test.FragmentTestActivity$TestFragment"
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The strange thing is that the container parameter in `onCreateView` is `null`.

Now, if I add the fragment programatically like so(just change the `onCreate` method of the Activity) the container is no longer null. Why?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fragment frag = new TestFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();
}
```

Comment: I am having a simmilar issue. I thought the container was part of the activity layout, where the fragment is embedded. How can that be null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation mentions that it can be null:

> public View
>   [onCreateView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater%2C%20android.view.ViewGroup%2C%20android.os.Bundle))(LayoutInflater
>   inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
>
> [...]
>
> container: ***If non-null***, this is the parent view that the
>   fragment's UI should be attached to. ***The fragment should not add the
>   view itself***, but this can be used to generate the LayoutParams of the
>   view.

To be clear: you shouldn't do anything like `container.addView(...)`.

Comment: That's not what he's doing though.  He's saying when inflating from a layout xml, the container is null even though there is a parent view the Fragment is contained in.  I don't think that's supposed to happen.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I know he isn't currently doing `container.addView(...)` but I was guessing he wanted to, and that's why he noticed that `container` is sometimes `null`. The docs say "If non-null" which means it is perfectly ok for it to be `null`, and it doesn't matter if it is `null` because you never need to add any views to it.

Comment: I want, for example, to have a BroadcastReceiver which will update the fragment in certain cases. Saving the container for future update would have been a great solution, but having a null container means I must find other way to do it