# Android fragments: container variable in onCreateView is null

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have an application that is only fragment based, and actually (i'm just creating basic content) i have only one fragment, declared directly into the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.italialinux.fragments.MainFragment"
        android:id="@+id/main_screen_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

And this layout is loaded inside main activity, with the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
    }
}
```

And the MainFragment class is the following:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    final static private long ONE_SECOND = 1000;
    final static private long TWENTY_SECONDS = ONE_SECOND * 20;

    private final static String TAG = "MainFragment";
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_reminder, container, false);
        return view;    
    }
```

And the new_reminder layout contains just two EditText and several labels.

The problem is that i cannot inflate the layout, since the container variable passed in onCreateView is null.

I saw many questions on SO, like the following: 
[Android Fragment is given a null container in onCreateView()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883831/android-fragment-is-given-a-null-container-in-oncreateview)

And all says that i need to use a transaction, but what i don't understood is: 
if i have a fragment that is immutable, in a layout, and doesn't need to change (like in that case, and like in many examples where you have a ListFragment that contains a list of items), how i can inflate the layout inside the current view?

With ListFragment it works, but what if i don't want to use it?

The onCreateView method is called correctly.

Comment: Might be unrelated, but why are you calling `super.onSaveInstanceState` inside `onCreateView`? and this answer mentions that the container can actually be null: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13586685/1561033

Comment: The onSaveInstanceState was added trying to fix this issue, if i remove that line i still have the problem. The problem is that the layout  R.layout.new_reminder  is not inflated in the fragment.

Comment: When you say it is not being inflated, what error message are you getting?

Comment: nothing! No erro, but the view doesn't appear in the fragment.

Comment: Would the view appear anyway, even if `container` had not been `null`, as you say it is? Wouldn't that `layout_width` set at `0dp` in the `<fragment>` element prevent it to be seen on screen anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main layout, try using `android:layout_width="match_parent"` instead of `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

And you shouldn't be calling `onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)` in `onCreate`; it is called by the framework when your fragment is going down to allow it to save its state.